# Запись разных значений в Sql server

Tags: c#, sql

Есть exe программа, написанная на C#. Она записывает значения в SQL Server. При запуске с моего пк, в базу пишет правильные значения ( 0,419, 0,356 ), как только запускаем на сервере значения идут, будто с коэффициентом х1000 ( 419, 356 ). Та же программа, та же база данных. Только машины разные. По какой причине может быть такое поведение?

Код, где изменяю значение и отправляю в базу данных:

```
 gapNumber = float.Parse("0,371");    
 result = Math.Round(gapNumber, 3).ToString(); 
 resultNum = float.Parse(result);
 insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(dbHeaders[count], resultNum);
```

На локальном пк запишет верно-0,371. На сервере значение будет-371

Comment: какой тип данных в колонке в базе данных? как вы записываете эти данные у себя в программе?

Comment: в базе данных - numeric(18,4).  В программе записываю при помощи оператора -  insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue

Comment: Лучше в вопрос соответствующий кусочек кода добавьте, а не в комментарий.

Comment: Разные региональные настройки на сервере и у вас?

Comment: Есть вероятность, что прблема может быть в локали. Например, если вы на локальной машине дробную часть от целой отделяете запятой, то на сервере запятая может означать просто разделитель разрядов в числе.

Comment: insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue полную версию этой строки с указанием типов передаваемых переменных укажите пожалуйста в вопросе

Comment: @A K♦ одинаковые настройки..

Comment: вместо Parameters.AddWithValue вызовите метод Parameters.Add  с указанием явного типа sql-параметра. И напишите в своём вопросе определение вашей ХП из sql-сервера, чтобы понять какие параметры и как у вас там происходит сохранение значений.

Comment: result = float.Parse(num, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @Konst CultureInfo.InvariantCulture не решило проблему. Объясните пожалуйста строку "определение вашей ХП из sql-сервера"

Comment: SQL-код вашей ХП (alter procedure ...)

Comment: Вы показали какой-то бред в примере кода. `float.Parse(0,371)` - это даже не скомпилируется. Далее вы зачем-то переводите результат в строку и снова парсите.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov спасибо за замечание. Исправил

Comment: Ну и по традиции: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) Как вам уже сказали, откажитесь от использования этого метода. Всегда нужно явно указывать тип в БД и проблем не будет.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Как здесь советовали ребята, использовал Parameters.Add. Проблема сохранялось уже у меня на машине ( было наоборот ). Применил CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, и уже вручную делил значение на 1000. Работает и у меня, и на сервере правильно.